# CSS Column Divs Help needed

Tags: css, html, fluid

I am trying to construct a page layout, where the left column has a fixed width and a height of 100% (of whatever the right column is) and the right column has a fluid width. I've tried various ways of doing it, but can't seem to get it right..

Here's my code:

```
<div id="pageHolder">
  <div id="topSection">
    header goes here
  </div>
  <div id="pageContainer">
    <div id="leftColumn">
      <div id="leftHolder">
        left stuff goes here
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightColumn">
      <div id="rightHolder">
        right stuff goes here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bottomSection">
    footer goes here
  </div>
</div>
```

And my css is:

```
body {
  height: 100%;
}
div#pageHolder {

}
div#topSection {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
div#pageContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
div#leftColumn {
  position: relative;   
  float: left;
  width: 285px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
div#leftHolder {
  padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
div#rightColumn {
  position: relative;   
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 285px;
}
div#rightHolder {
  padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
div#bottomSection {
  clear: both;
}
```

If someone could help me out, that would be fantastic :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out:

```
div#leftColumn {
  position: absolute;   
  float: left;
  width: 285px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

**Edit: On second thought perhaps using maxwidth and maxheight could do something to help you if you want to keep position: relative.

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked, just needed to add left: 0px; :)

Comment: If you can, try it on different browsers just to make sure it works everywhere.

Comment: Internet Explorer tends to make odds stuff happen :S

Answer (score 2):

http://css-tricks.com/the-perfect-fluid-width-layout/

as i see the '[live example](http://css-tricks.com/examples/PerfectFluidWidthLayout/)' this is what you're asking for

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to replace your `body` definition with `body, html` in your css, as well as add a height to `pageHolder`

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
div#pageHolder {
  height: 100%;
}
```

It's pretty annoying though because you will get unnecessary scrollbars regardless of the content inside. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Will add that, thanks.. But I'm trying to get the left column to be 100% height (depending on how much content is inside the right column), if that makes sense?

Comment: By 00% height (depending on how much content is inside the right column), you mean the same height as the right column, correct?

Comment: Yep, that's what I mean, sorry :)

Comment: Ah, well I'm glad Partial could be of help :) Cheers.